# Should unique_lock with try_to_lock owns the mutex even if lock fails?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-2012, mutex

The following code results in different outputs with VS2012 Express and gcc 4.7.2, which is what [ideone](http://ideone.com) uses. For the record, I tried to compile with MinGW, but it does not implement C++11's <mutex> as stated [here](http://kbokonseriousstuff.blogspot.com.br/2011/08/c11-standard-library-threads-with-mingw.html).

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::mutex m;
    {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m, std::try_to_lock);
            std::cout << (bool)l <<std::endl;
    }
    {
            m.lock();
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m, std::try_to_lock);
            std::cout << (bool)l <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

In visual studio, the second test prints 0, which means the lock does not own the mutex, since it was already locked.

With gcc, the second test prints 1, meaning that the lock aquired the mutex, even if already locked, as in `std::adopt_lock`.

Which one is correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard defines that `std::unique_lock` constructor with:

> ```
> unique_lock(mutex_type& m, try_to_lock_t);
> ```
>
> *Requires:* The supplied Mutex type shall meet the Lockable requirements (30.2.5.3). If mutex_type is not a recursive mutex **the calling thread does not own the mutex**.

So the behavior is undefined since you're violating the requirement for that call. (`std::mutex` is not recursive.)